# IIS7 403 for custom mime type

Tags: iis-7, mime-type

I have added in a custom mime type (epub) as "application/epub" into IIS7.

This was working originally but something seems to have stopped it working and now we get the response "403 Forbidden: body content-type denied".

This is a strange message, and google brings up very few results, none of them seem relevant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to our IT admin and we figured out that it was the firewall that was blocking the request.

Comment: More detail would be helpful to the next person who encounters this issue (what firewall software? what settings needed to be changed, etc.)

Comment: It's a firebox 550e. The solution according to our IT guy was: "dont try and block any attachments that are downloadable". I'm not sure of the exact settings.